# Zk 5.0.11 NullPointerException when using fulfill attribute inside listbox

Tags: zk

when using a simple example of fulfill, inside a listbox, I get a null pointer exception, which I can't get rid of.
http://zkfiddle.org/sample/38ipduo/44-Listbox-fulfill-attr-error

The fiddle above provides a working example of the error. 
Debugging the code, I can see the next line

```
org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl$FulfillListener.<init>(UiEngineImpl.java:2058)
```

being called twice. The first time everything seems fine, but the second time it seems some data is not filled in, causing the NPE.
Any ideas how can I work the fiddle work correctly? 
Man thanks in advance.

e.g.

```
<listcell>
  <button id="btn" label="show" ></button>
      <div fulfill="btn.onClick">
      Hello world
      </div>
  <textbox value="@{person.name}" inplace="true" ></textbox>
</listcell>
```

I'm trying a list with a single record, as one initial answer in the zk forums 
suggested several id="btn" elements may be causing conflicts. THe fiddle is using zk 5. I have tried with 6.5 and got a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error when using 6.5 you see that zk trys to add the `div`
to the `button` as a child which is impossible.
I am not sure if this is a bug you may check the `fulfill` part of zk doc.
Using [Event Listening](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Listening) and add the `Component` on java side should be the best workaround.